# Bootstrap-modal pop up on top to Flash

Tags: jquery, flash, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter's Bootstrap plugin `bootstrap-modal`.  It works well except for when there is a flash element behind it.  When the bootstrap-modal dialogue box up, and there is a flash element behind it, the flash element is on top of everything else.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an attribute to the `<object>` or `<embed>` tag to allow html to display over your flash content, since this feature is turned off by default. So, add the following attribute to your tag and the modal popup should work fine:

```
wmode="opaque"
```

[Documentation](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)