# wmode=transparent for Youtube video Iframe not working in IE with bootstrap modal

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, z-index

I have a web app in which I am embedding Youtube videos using the iframe tag. I am also using bootstrap modal. So the issue arises in IE when the bootstrap modal fails to overlap the youtube video. Now i googled for this and I found a lot of answers saying that adding wmode=transparent should fix the issue. Well, It did not for me.

Since I couldnt figure out a way for setting up a jsfiddle, I went to the bootstrap modal demo site and edited their code and added a youtube video. Please refer the below screenshot for more details.

[image]

And when I clicked on the "Launch demo modal", it did not work

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is not working or have a solution for this?

Here is the youtube video code which i put just above that modal button

```
<iframe class="yt-video-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WEROVWDp3n0?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata&amp;wmode=transparent"></iframe>
```

I am using:

- IE 9
- bootstrap modal version 2.3.1
- Youtube API version 2

Comment: You can use bootply http://bootply.com/ to play with bootstrap. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439444/bootstrap-modal-pop-up-on-top-to-flash . Try to use `wmode="opaque"`.

Comment: that certainly helped, but why it does not work if we try to append it to the end of the url ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using wmode=opaque instead of wmode=transparent. But check with chrome. By the way, if you do it on firebug it wont work.